# Jave, report is not show jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have issue in my program, I want to generate this report when the "Delivery Note Upload" button pressed.
I have create the report my using jasper report and it's working in preview fine
but when I try to connected to my java app nothing showing when I press the button.

this is my code:

```
btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Delivery Note Upload");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/storge?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=true","root","");
                JasperDesign jdesign = JRXmlLoader.load(null, "C:\\Users\\MAlasmari\\eclipse-workspace\\Test\\src\\MA\\Blank_A41.jrxml");
                
                String sqlC= "select *,max(location),max(Date) from itemdelivery";
                JRDesignQuery upquery = new JRDesignQuery();
                upquery.setText(sqlC);
                
                jdesign.setQuery(upquery);
            
                JasperReport jreport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jdesign);
                JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, null, conn);

                JasperViewer.viewReport(jprint, true);
                
            } catch (JRException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReportsContext.getProperty(String)" because "this.jasperReportsContext" is null
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.getProperty(JRPropertiesUtil.java:150)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1571)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1549)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:263)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:219)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:194)
    at MA.UserM$3.actionPerformed(UserM.java:131)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have passed a `null` as the context when loading the ".jrxml" file.   That has lead to a NPE in the implementation of the `load` method.

You need to construct a reports context instance, or call `DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance()` to create a default context.  Then pass that rather than a `null` in the `load` call.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue, it was from database connection in:

```
JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, null, conn);
```

in code above the connection is wrong
So, I made file for Sql connection and call the file in here
As like this.

```
JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, null, connection);
```